# Is every compact set in $\mathbb R^2$ a continuous image of some compact set of $\mathbb R$?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces, continuity, compactness

Is it true that for every compact subset $A$ of $\mathbb R^2$ , there exist a compact set $B$ in $\mathbb R$ such that there is a continuous surjection from $B$ to $A$ ?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Any compact metric space is a continuous image of the Cantor set.

Comment: Do you have a reference, please?

Comment: @Siminore This is Theorem 30.7 of Willard's General Topology.